# Comparing two JavaScript code snippets

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Are these 2 JavaScript code snippets equivalent?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    (function(){
        return 'something';
    })();
});
```

and this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  return (function() {
    return "something";
  })();
});
```

I was trying coffescript. Converting the above first code to coffescript and converting it back to JS gives the second snippet. So, I wanted to know if they are exactly same. Isn't returning a function from within a function related to closures?

Comment: Functions in CoffeeScript return the value of their last expression, that's where the extra `return` in the second one comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They'll be the same, yeah. Except that the second one is going to use 1 more unit of stack memory.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the `.ready` method uses the return value of its callback. If it does, then the examples are different. If the return value is ignored then its the same.

If you stop to think of it, you can "simplify out" that immediately invoked function expression. Doing this turns the first example into

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    'something';
});
```

and the second into

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    return 'something';
});
```